# Replace imperative for loop with lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

I am currently writing a game for fun and I notice I still fall back to the "old" way of looping. Can anyone lend me a hand and show me how this method would look like using lambdas?

```
public GameObject findClosestEnemy(Game game, GameObject actor) {
    Double minDistance = null;
    GameObject closestEnemy = null;

    for (GameObject o : game.getObjects()) {
        if (isNoEnemy(actor, o)) {
            continue;
        }

        double distance = actor.calculateMinEuclideanDistance(o);
        if (minDistance == null || distance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = distance;
            closestEnemy = o;
        }
    }
    return closestEnemy;
}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with a [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

The `if`/`continue` check maps to [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Use [`min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) to find the smallest object. `min()` accepts a custom comparator, which is how we can tell it to compare enemies by their Euclidean distance.

Instead of returning null let's return `Optional<GameObject>` to ensure the caller handles the case where there is no closest enemy.

```
public Optional<GameObject> findClosestEnemy(Game game, GameObject actor) {
    return game.getObjects().stream()
        .filter(o -> !isNoEnemy(actor, o))
        .min(Comparator.comparing(actor::calculateMinEuclideanDistance));
}
```

Also, consider using more member functions. It seems like `findClosestEnemy()` should be a method in the `Game` class, and `isNoEnemy()` should be in `GameObject`. And avoid negations in identifiers: it should probably just be `isEnemy()`. `actor.isEnemy(o)` or `o.isEnemyOf(actor)` both read better to me than `isNoEnemy(actor, o)`.

Comment: I am still hesitant to put too much into the objects as they grow quickly. I still play around with it and will see what works best. Great input thank you.